# Is there an easier method to solve this question on permutation?

Tags: permutations

Question: Calculate the largest possible order of any permutation in S10.

My approach:
List out all possible order in S10 then find the LCM of each, got lcm(5,3,2) = 30 as the largest possible order.

I'm just wondering if there's a quicker method to solve this question as it took me like forever to list out each possible orders and find their LCM respectively.

Comment: You're forgetting the constraint that the cycles have to be disjoint in the decomposition of a permutation.